# Recycler View item add

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

i have a recyclerview to display data from api feed, however it is adding blank rows of data. How do i only add the data needed and if does not match criteria do not add blank row?

here is my data adapter:

```
public class DataAdapter extends 
 RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private ArrayList<Included> includedData;
    private Included matchDataIncluded;
    private Data matchData;


    public DataAdapter(ArrayList<Included> includedData) {
        this.includedData = includedData;
        this.matchDataIncluded = matchDataIncluded;
    }


    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            if (Objects.equals(includedData.get(position).getType(), "competitions") && includedData.get(position).getId() != null) {
                holder.tvCompetitionName.setText(includedData.get(position).getAttributes().);
            }
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return includedData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView tvCompetitionName;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvCompetitionName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.competitionNameTV);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this,

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (Objects.equals(includedData.get(position).getType(), "competitions") && includedData.get(position).getId() != null) {
            holder.tvCompetitionName.setText(includedData.get(position).getAttributes().);
        }
    }


}
```

Since the size of recyclerview is the size of "includedData" and OnBindViewHolder you put condition due to which you are getting empty row, just remove the conditon, data will be displayed.

Comment: Thanks, yeah thats what i originally had but i need the condition as only need to display data matching that condition, the rows are blank because those objects have data but not matching condition, so i need to exclude those rows that dont match condition

Comment: @MinatoN3886, so you must add the value in "includedData" when condition is met, rather than creating a check on "OnBindViewholder"

Comment: sorry i did not understand what you mean by that, could you give me an example?

Comment: use this condition, if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            if (Objects.equals(someObjet.getType(), "competitions") && someObjet.getId() != null) {
                includedData.add(someObjet);
            }
        }

Comment: in actiivty or fragment or whereever